# Exception Handling Framework for Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception

I want to create a exception handling framework for my application so that I can handle errors and exception throughout the application form a common/central point. I'm using a Java EE application.

Comment: i.e.: What's the question? :-)

Comment: "exception handling framework", by this I mean some framework which can make my work easy by handling the exceptions and doing the necessary action on any exception.

Comment: `catch` and `finally` are a pretty good framework. You just need to plug in your app-specific actions, and they take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to know the difference between checked and unchecked exceptions. Not only the technical difference, but also best practice. I recommend reading an article like this one: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/checked-or-unchecked-exceptions.html

From my personal experience with medium-sized projects, I recommend using only unchecked exceptions (other people may have other opinions).

Answer (score 1):

You can create `custom/user defined` exceptions by extending the Exception class in java. If that is what you meant, [check this simple example](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-user-defined-exception.html).

You can similarly create different user defined exception from the previously created exception and create a framework as you want.

[Java Exception framework is designed as given here.](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=909&tbm=isch&tbnid=5L4T2NS6C98pAM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.artima.com/javaseminars/modules/Exceptions/&docid=Y5FxSA8TFfoJMM&imgurl=http://www.artima.com/javaseminars/modules/Exceptions/images/BWThrowableFamily.gif&w=550&h=287&ei=g_CxT76MOrHKmAXR6-2pCQ&zoom=1)